# D3 Scatter Plot Not Implementing Zoom Interaction Properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am a novice at D3 and I was trying to implement zoom/pan functionality on my scatter plot. Unfortunately, after following a tutorial, whenever I zoom on the visualization, the axes ticks disappear but the visualization doesn't readjust. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
//Adding zoom and pan interaction to visualization
         var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([.5, 20])
            .extent([0, 0], [width, height])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

// This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
            .call(zoom);
 function zoomed(){
            // recover the new scale
            var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
            var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

            // update axes with these new boundaries
            xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
            yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

            //update positions
            dotGraph.selectAll("circle")
                .attr("cx", d => newX(d.installs))
                .attr("cy", d => newY(d.reviews));
        }
```

The full code is located here: https://jsfiddle.net/wkLr7hob/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comment out the extent portion of your code you'll see the zoom working as expected¹, minus the enforcement of an extent.

You're not providing a valid extent to `zoom.extent()`, you pass two arrays:

```
.extent([0, 0], [width, height])
```

Instead of one `[[0,0],[width,height]]`,

But this still doesn't fix the extent of the zoom behavior, I believe you are looking for `translateExtent` which limits the panning extent of the chart - however, if we use `[[0,0],[width,height]]`, zooming out to 0.5 is not possible: the extent shown would be greater than the translate extent. So we might as well set the minimum scale to 1.

Doing that we get [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wb6tzovy/).

*¹ Also, in the zoom function, you're selecting all circles in `dotGraph`, but `dotGraph` is a selection of circles already - so we can drop the `selectAll("circle")` method in the zoom function. Otherwise the circles won't update.*